# Add multiple pages to report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How to add multiple pages to *JR* report with the same layout and different content?

I am trying to print payslips for employees. So instead of printing each pay slip for an employee I want to print all of them together in one jasper report. one payslip per page with multiple pages according to the number of employees.

Comment: are all your data available as SQL result set? If so, there is a simpler way to meet your requirements as JasperReports provides an implicit handling for SQL queries.

Comment: Yes I added a SQL query and got the data. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate your data in a List or Map. Then, use the appropriate `JRDataSource - JRMapDataSource or JRBeanDataSource` and pass it to the `JReport exporter - PDF, XLS, whatever`. You can even populate a table with your datasource and will print each row as a separate payslips (if you have populated your data correctly).

In a nutshell, populate your data in a collection and then iterate through the collection in your `JasperReport Detail Band`.

I would highly recommend using `iReport` Designer tool for `JasperReports`.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but still its not clear to be. pardon me i am still new to jasper reporting.

Comment: One of the ways you can populate your data on the report is by filling out a List of your PaySlip objects. Then, you can pass that List to a JasperReports DataSource, which in turn is used on your template to generate and format the report. I highly recommend using iReport tool to visually create your templates. A quick tip would be to create a field ($F{myPaySlipList}) on your report and then you can pass your List of PaySlip objects to it.

Comment: Here is neat and quick tutorial using iReport. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=103MUpnyrvk

Comment: Thank you so much. il give it a try.

Comment: No problem. Dont forget to approve the answer if it has helped you. Regards!